# VoiceOver not working correctly for UITableViewHeaderFooterView until being reused

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

I have a `UITableView` with 2 sections, each of them uses an instance of a custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` class. When using `VoiceOver` to read out the elements of the `UITableView`, it reads the second section's header correctly: " [Header Title], *heading* " but it only reads the [Header Title] (doesn't say *heading*) for the first section. This is true every time we instantiate our `UITableView` and nothing else is changed. However, if the first section's header gets out of the screen and and comeback later, the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` instance will be dequeued and reused, but this time, after being reused, `VoiceOver` will read out correctly the same section header: "[Header Title], *heading* ".

I've tried overriding `UIAccessibilityTraits` on my custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` class declaration and set it as `.header`, just in case my custom class was modifying the `UIAccessibilityTraits` silently, but this didn't change anything.

Does anyone know if this is a common issue or if there's some workaround to solve this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Still trying to fix it

Comment: If you think this is a bug, it would be great if you reported it to Apple. Thanks.